# OpenLayers Handler Point image

Tags: openlayers-2

I am trying to draw a marker by EditingToolbar but I don't know to change style of point.

I want to draw an image instead of a default point.

Could you show me how I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the styling documentation](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/feature_styling.html), you have to define a custom stylemap and define a custom style for the element. You shuld override the styles 'default', 'select' ant 'temporay'

Answer (score 0):

Here it is an simple example of how to do what you want :
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Openlayers_POI_layer_example